# Why am I getting this error after parsing the cookie value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, cookies, next.js

I'm successfully setting the cookie and when I do `console.log(getCookie('key'))` I see this:

```
[{"pic":"https://something.jpg","des":"something","price":"something","score":"something","id":0,"explink":"something"}]
```

But when I run `JSON.parse(getCookie('key'))` I get this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

I was trying to use this:

```
import Layout from '../components/layout';
import { useState, createContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import AppContext from '../components/AppContext';
import '../styles/globals.css';
import { getCookies, getCookie, setCookie, deleteCookie } from 'cookies-next';

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [count, setcount] = useState(0);
  const [card, setcard] = useState([]);
  setCookie('key', JSON.stringify(card));
  setcard(JSON.parse(getCookie('key')));
  return (
    <div>
      <AppContext.Provider
        value={{
          count,
          setcount,
          card,
          setcard,
 
        }}
      >
        <Layout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
      </AppContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Why am I getting this error?

I also tried `setcard(getCookie('key'));` but I got this error:

> Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to
> prevent an infinite loop.
>
> This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will
> be displayed in the terminal window.

Comment: check if getCookie('key') returns something.. it looks like JSON.parse obtaining "undefined", therefore "u" is at position 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getCookie('key')` already parsed. So, you got this error. Try this:
`setcard(getCookie('key'))`

> Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

I think you need to `setcard` inside `useEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setcard(getCookie('key'))
}, [])
```

Comment: Why do cookies disappear when I refresh the page?

Comment: You have to specify `/` as path in setCookie() function, so cookie will be available on every path of your site.